# Mark statement expression as maybe unused

Tags: c, gcc, clang

How do I mark a [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), i.e.

```
({struct Value * t = expr; set(t,val); t;})
```

as maybe unused, i.e.

```
__attribute__((unused))
```

It's autogenerated code, with side effects. Deducing whether the result is unused and swapping in `(void)0` for `t` at generation time would increase complexity significantly. The neatest solution would be to mark it as maybe unused, else I'll have to do `-Wno-unused-value`.

Comment: Why would you do that? Either you have the statement in the code or you don't. If you want to disble part of the code at compiler-time, use the preprocessor.

Comment: @Olaf It's autogenerated code, with side effects. The neatest solution would be to mark it as maybe unused, else I'll have to do `-Wno-unused-value`.

Comment: What I wrote applies to automatically generated code, too. But you have a third option: just don't emit that code.

Comment: @Olaf Deducing whether the result is unused and swapping in `(void)0` for t would increase complexity significantly.

Comment: No it would not. However, please clarify what you want to accomplish actually. As given, it looks like an XY-problem. Hmm... do you mean not to use the **result** of an expression? You already did that with `(void)0`.

Comment: @Olaf It is not an XY question. You do not know the codebase I'm working on, and you do not know which solution is more elegant. Why not give me the benefit of the doubt? This is a valid programming question.

Comment: Is the final `t;` elegant?

Comment: @WeatherVane In this instance, yes it is.

Comment: Why? You have used `t` so you don't need a dummy reference to defeat a compiler warning.

Comment: I did not vote to close as OT. It is just not clear what you actually mean.

Comment: @WeatherVane: `t;` can generate a compiler warning. Perhaps that is what OP wants to suppress. However, as `t` is executed, it actually **is** used (at least for a side-effect if `t` is `volatile`).

Comment: @WeatherVane I have used `t` to return the value `t` from the statement expression. It's sometimes used, sometimes not.

Comment: A statement expression does not return anything (where would it?). That would only be an assignment-expression or a `return` statement.

Comment: @Olaf The [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) beg to differ. "the result value of a statement expression undergoes array and function pointer decay, and is returned by value to the enclosing expression"

Comment: Again: An _expression statement_ cannot be enclosed in an expression. So it cannot return anything. Feel free to prove me wrong: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html You refer to a **gcc extension**! Please make that clear in your question. However, it is still not clear what you want to accomplish; You have to show the surrounding code. Think about a better way by using a function.

Comment: @Olaf Your link specifies nothing about statement expressions. The question is tagged `gcc` and `clang`, and I refer to the (commonly used) extension by name: statement expressions.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] **in** your qestion. Do not just use external links.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be quite disturbing if you use such things in macros or alike. I usually silence such warnings by using a completely useless assignment at the end:

```
t = t;
```

This has two effects: the compiler now thinks that `t` is used, and also that the result of that is an rvalue so nobody can try to take the address of the whole `({ })` expression.

Comment: Unfortunately I then get `explicitly assigning value of variable of type 'struct Value *' to itself [-Werror,-Wself-assign]`

Comment: @Alec stop using `-Wself-assign` perhaps

Comment: @M.M I think that `-Wno-unused-value` is the least egregious of the two options, so that's what I'm using at the moment - unless anyone comes up with a solution to mark an expression result (not a variable) as maybe unused.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use:

```
// tell compiler to shut up about unused variables
#define VARIABLE_USED(_sym) \
    _variable_used(!!_sym)

__attribute__((__always_inline__)) static inline
void
_variable_used(int flg)
{
}
```

- You may need variants based on your actual types.  But, because of the `!!` trick, the above works for almost any intrinsic type (inc. pointers)
- You may need `inline` instead of `static inline` depending on your compiler
- Without `__attribute__((__always_inline__))` if your compiler complains about it

So, somewhere in the code just add `VARIABLE_USED(my_unused_variable);` for all your unused symbols.

NOTE: This is *zero* overhead (i.e. generates no extra code).  It may seem like it does with the formulation of the argument, but because of the inline definition, it gets optimized away.  But, it does trick the compiler into thinking the variable has been used.

The above is what I've used for a long time.  But, I just thought up a possibly simpler variant [this is *untested*]:

```
// tell compiler to shut up about unused variables
#define VARIABLE_USED(_sym) \
    do { \
        if (1) \
            break;
        if (!! _sym) \
            break; \
    } while (0)
```

These macros *might* work for a struct, as is:

```
struct foobar foo;
...
VARIABLE_USED(&foo);
```